# Array index swaps when its not supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, checkbox

I currently have a dynamically generated `checkbox` which when clicked creates a table. Multiple selections can be selected on my `checkbox` and I store this in an array. I have a loop for storing different selections e.g 1st, 2nd and 3rd checked selections.

> Checkbox

1. option_one
2. option_two
3. options_three

The problem I am facing is, if I select the options in ascending order like 1>2>3 the tables are generated correctly:

- Table_One
- Table_two
- Table_Three

However if I I select in a descending order, or I mix it up, option_one always ends up being passed as the first selection even when this isn't true.

My code:

```
$(document).on("change", ".tbl_list", function () {
    var tbls = [];
    $("input:checkbox[name='tbl[]']:checked").each(function () {
        tbls.push($(this).val());
        var tbl2Name = " ";
        var tbl3Name = " ";
        var tblName = " ";
        for (i = 0; i < tbls.length; i++) {
            if (i === 0) {
                tblName = tbls[i];
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                tbl2Name = tbls[i];
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                tbl3Name = tbls[i];
            }
        }
        $("#table").html(tblName);
```

Where `tbl_list` is the `checkbox` class-name and `tbl[]` is the name. So why does `tblName` always assume the value of the first object in the checkbox list?

Comment: Can you include some html, or a jsfiddle.

Comment: You set it to the variable holding the first table. ` $("#table").html(tblName);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break this down a bit, every time one of your checkboxes changes you create a brand new array

```
$(document).on("change", ".tbl_list", function () {
    var tbls = [];
```

Then you loop through all the checked checkboxes filling this list

```
$("input:checkbox[name='tbl[]']:checked").each(function () {
    tbls.push($(this).val());
```

jquery `.each` will iterate over all the checkboxes which are checked, it does this in the order they appear in the DOM, not in the order you happen to have checked them in (why would it? how would it know?)

If you want to preserrve the *order that you checked them in* then you need to maintain a persistant list, and push a new item to the end of the list when checked, and remove an item when unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

After the suggestions I made a few amendments and it now works as intended.

```
var tbls = [];
$(document).on("change", ".tbl_list", function () {
    if (this.checked){
        tbls.push($(this).val());
        console.log(tbls);
        var tbl2Name = " ";
        var tbl3Name = " ";
        var tblName = " ";
        for (i = 0; i < tbls.length; i++) {
            if (i === 0) {
                tblName = tbls[i];
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                tbl2Name = tbls[i];
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                tbl3Name = tbls[i];
            }
        }
    }

        $("#table").html(tblName);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("tblN", tblName);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("tblN2", tbl2Name);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("tblN3", tbl3Name);
```

Comment: You're never removing an item if the user unchecks it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //push into array

     else { 
       //remove from array 

    }
});
```

Cant you just check which checkbox has been selected and add its value to an array this way you can keep the order.

Comment: Yep simple and functional.